# Comparison Function: How can I hide the text when user slide to left or right of the comparison slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this comparison function which allow user to slide left and right to view the before and after image.

All working well (got the codes from codepen).

One issue though, I would like to have a text on the left and right side of the image (no issue) and when user slide to left, I want the left text (currently showing as "Text Left") to disappear when the slider nearly reaching the "Text Left" block and appear again when the slider away from "Text Left" block, same functionality for the "Text Right" block too.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? You can look at the code here. https://codepen.io/drstrangelovesg/pen/Kjpevp

Thank you in advance guys.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ba-slider').each(function () {
        var cur = $(this);
        // Adjust the slider
        var width = cur.width() + 'px';
        cur.find('.resize img').css('width', width);
        // Bind dragging events
        drags(cur.find('.handle'), cur.find('.resize'), cur);
    });
});

// Update sliders on resize. 
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.ba-slider').each(function () {
        var cur = $(this);
        var width = cur.width() + 'px';
        cur.find('.resize img').css('width', width);
    });
});

function drags(dragElement, resizeElement, container) {

    // Initialize the dragging event on mousedown.
    dragElement.on('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {

        dragElement.addClass('draggable');
        resizeElement.addClass('resizable');

        // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
        var startX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

        // Get the initial position
        var dragWidth = dragElement.outerWidth(),
            posX = dragElement.offset().left + dragWidth - startX,
            containerOffset = container.offset().left,
            containerWidth = container.outerWidth();

        // Set limits
        minLeft = containerOffset + 10;
        maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10;

        // Calculate the dragging distance on mousemove.
        dragElement.parents().on("mousemove touchmove", function (e) {

            // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
            var moveX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

            leftValue = moveX + posX - dragWidth;

            // Prevent going off limits
            if (leftValue < minLeft) {
                leftValue = minLeft;
            } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
                leftValue = maxLeft;
            }

            // Translate the handle's left value to masked divs width.
            widthValue = (leftValue + dragWidth / 2 - containerOffset) * 100 / containerWidth + '%';

            // Set the new values for the slider and the handle. 
            // Bind mouseup events to stop dragging.
            $('.draggable').css('left', widthValue).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
                resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
            });
            $('.resizable').css('width', widthValue);
        }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function () {
            dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
            resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function (e) {
        dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
        resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
    });
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the slider reach the maximum value, the label will be hidden, otherwise will be displayed as block

```
if (leftValue === minLeft)
  document.getElementById("leftElement").style.display = 'none';
else      
  document.getElementById("leftElement").style.display = 'block';`
```

I changed the max and min value to +- 80 just for demo purpose, to be more visible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ba-slider").each(function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    // Adjust the slider
    var width = cur.width() + "px";
    cur.find(".resize img").css("width", width);
    // Bind dragging events
    drags(cur.find(".handle"), cur.find(".resize"), cur);
  });
});

// Update sliders on resize.
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".ba-slider").each(function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    var width = cur.width() + "px";
    cur.find(".resize img").css("width", width);
  });
});

function drags(dragElement, resizeElement, container) {
  // Initialize the dragging event on mousedown.
  dragElement
    .on("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
      dragElement.addClass("draggable");
      resizeElement.addClass("resizable");

      // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
      var startX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      // Get the initial position
      var dragWidth = dragElement.outerWidth(),
        posX = dragElement.offset().left + dragWidth - startX,
        containerOffset = container.offset().left,
        containerWidth = container.outerWidth();

      // Set limits
      minLeft = containerOffset + 80;
      maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 80;
   

      // Calculate the dragging distance on mousemove.
      dragElement
        .parents()
        .on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
          // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
          var moveX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

          leftValue = moveX + posX - dragWidth;

          // Prevent going off limits
          if (leftValue <= minLeft) {
            leftValue = minLeft;
          } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
            leftValue = maxLeft;
          }
        
          if (leftValue === minLeft)
             document.getElementById("leftElement").style.display = 'none';
          else      
             document.getElementById("leftElement").style.display = 'block';
        
         if (leftValue === maxLeft)
            document.getElementById("rightElement").style.display = 'none';
         else      
            document.getElementById("rightElement").style.display = 'block';
      
        

          // Translate the handle's left value to masked divs width.
          widthValue =
            (leftValue + dragWidth / 2 - containerOffset) *
              100 /
              containerWidth +
            "%";

          // Set the new values for the slider and the handle.
          // Bind mouseup events to stop dragging.
          $(".draggable")
            .css("left", widthValue)
            .on("mouseup touchend touchcancel", function() {
              $(this).removeClass("draggable");
              resizeElement.removeClass("resizable");
            });
          $(".resizable").css("width", widthValue);
        })
        .on("mouseup touchend touchcancel", function() {
          dragElement.removeClass("draggable");
          resizeElement.removeClass("resizable");
        });
      e.preventDefault();
    })
    .on("mouseup touchend touchcancel", function(e) {
      dragElement.removeClass("draggable");
      resizeElement.removeClass("resizable");
    });
}
```

```css
.rinse-away-container {
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .rinse-away-container {
    margin-bottom: 10rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .rinse-away-container {
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
  }
}
.ba-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1045px;
  margin: 5rem auto 0;
}
.ba-slider img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.ba-slider .label-left,
.ba-slider .label-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
}
.ba-slider .label-right {
  right: 0;
}
.resize {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.handle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

.handle:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: -32px 0 0 -5px;
  content: "";
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.draggable:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: -32px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="rinse-away-container">
    <div class="container rinse-away-content">
      <div class="compare-image-container">
        <div class="ba-slider">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/8cC5xQh/test1.png" alt="Test 1">
          <div id="leftElement" class="label-left">Text Left</div>
          <div class="resize">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FkQQJ8j/test2.png" alt="Test 2">
          </div>
          <div id="rightElement" class="label-right">Text Right</div>
          <span class="handle"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Elias thanks for the full explanation. I tested but there is one issue though, when the mouse leaves the compare area, the hidden text will appear again. I found this sample: https://codyhouse.co/demo/image-comparison-slider/index.html showing exactly how I want mine to work too. Don't really want to use the codyhouse example as it required additional jquery. Is there a way I can hide the text until the user slide to the right again (reaching somewhere in the center of image), ie, if the slide to left, the left text will disappear and remain hidden until the user slide to the right.

Comment: Hi @Elias, another issue is that it track the mouse even when my mouse is out of the image area, thus causing the text to appear and disappear when user are moving their mouse outside of the image.

Comment: @StrangeLove here is what i tried now: https://jsfiddle.net/5vdqyupL/1/  I moved that little logic in "mouseup" but there are still some cases where it crash, for example if the slider reaches the min/max zone, the labels goes nuts and a rerun is needed. :( but i'll take a look tomorrow maybe

Comment: @StrangeLove I think it's done, test if and something is not ok let me know:  https://jsfiddle.net/EliasBlack/h3mozdka/5/  If it's ok i'll edit the main answer with the correct solution.

Comment: thank you for your kind help. I tried but don't seem to work, the text remains there even after I slide all the way to the end. Again thank you for helping.

Accepting your answer as it is close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just check in your mousemove function in which direction you are going depending on the direction, hide or show the labels.

```
dragElement
  .parents()
  .on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
  // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
  var moveX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
  if(moveX < startX) {
    //dragleft
    $('.label-left').hide();
    $('.label-right').show();
  }else{
    //dragtight
    $('.label-right').hide();
    $('.label-left').show();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Lapskaus, how can I also make it that when the user slides back to the center of the image, both text will appear again?

Comment: store the initial location of your slider in a variable and in the mousemove listener you check if the slider is back at its original center location. You could go as far as define an offset to that location at which it "snaps" back to the middle